# Organize Existing Posts from the Admin Area to a New Category

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to create and admin area that allows you to add, reorder, and remove existing posts to a 'featured' category by selecting from a dropdown menu that has a list of categories and posts in that category, preferably with a drag and drop functionality.

Would this be done with a custom post type? If so, can anyone direct me to an article somewhere that can get me started on doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not *exactly* what you're asking for, check out [Zoninator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/zoninator/). It does everything you're asking except that it doesn't use categories. I'm guessing you just wanted to use categories to target a featured area of the site, and if so, this does that extremely well. It even has a widget for listing the posts, so no code is required.

Comment: Weird. the  Wordpress site has been doing this for me all day. I'll wait till the issue is resolved and report back. http://d.pr/i/Gc0L

Comment: That is an amazing plugin, but you're right, it definitely falls short.